# EmailMessage.ToAddress is validated on one sandbox but not the other (INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS)

Tags: email, validation, exception, dml, dmlexception

I have two sandboxes both running Summer '17, and the following code works on one but throws INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS on the other:

```
Case c = new Case();
insert c;

EmailMessage em = new EmailMessage();
em.parentId = c.Id;
em.ToAddress = 'purposefully incorrect email'; // incorrect email
insert em; // works on one but throws INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS on the other
```

EmailMessage doesn't have any custom validation rules or triggers on either of sandboxes. Is EmailMessage validation configurable somewhere? What determines whether the address is validated on insert or not, why is there a discrepancy between sandboxes?

Comment: If your concern is about validation of the email address with brackets, I would edit your post to clarify it. Otherwise, you'll get answers telling you to remove the brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like when Email-to-Case is enabled, validation of ToAddress field is disabled. Those other sandboxes have Email-to-Case enabled and that's why inserting EmailMessage with invalid email in ToAddress field is allowed. And you need to be careful because once Email-to-Case is enabled, you can't disable it :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi try with below code,

```
Case c = new Case();
insert c;
EmailMessage em = new EmailMessage();
em.parentId = c.Id;
em.ToAddress = 'test@example.com';
insert em;
```

Comment: I know it will work everywhere without parentheses. What I want to know is why the email is validated in some sandboxes but not in others.

Comment: In other sandbox are you using try catch statements?

Comment: No, it just passes without any exception (I'm running the code through Developer Console).